# Parse a date object string and get time in milliseconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am storing a `new Date()` in my mongodb.

I am trying to see if the date is less than 5 minutes ago, so I tried:

```
// not working, maybe because the "previousTime" date object is now a string instead.
var isRecent = new Date().getTime() - previousTime.getTime() < 300000

// not working either, parseDate(previousTime).getTime() always gives the same 1443646800000 value
var isRecent = new Date().getTime() - parseDate(previousTime).getTime() < 3000;

function parseDate (input) {
  var parts = input.match(/(\d+)/g);
  // new Date(year, month [, date [, hours[, minutes[, seconds[, ms]]]]])
  return new Date(parts[0], parts[1]-1, parts[2]); // months are 0-based
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `previousTime`?  This question is unanswerable as it stands.

Comment: @ChaseSandmann In my question I said "date object string" and also in the description "maybe because the "previousTime" date object is now a string instead." So basically a date object, as string: `new Date().toString()`. I found out the answer is just to put the date string inside Date.parse() which gets the time in milliseconds since epoch.

Answer (score 0):

Put the date string inside Date.parse() which gets the time in milliseconds since epoch.

For example:

```
var dateAsString = new Date().toString();
var dateInMSSinceEpoch = Date.parse(dateAsString);
```